# Updating Android Studio to version 0.4.0. nothing works! Which fixes?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've made some waste code. After some mistakes I checkout latest commit. I expected to restart with any without any hitch. But building project now I receive the message:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_i8190n-47900693715f5036
Uploading file
local path: /Path/to/file.apk
remote path: /path/to/file/com.example
Local path doesn't exist.
(* I've removed complete local and remote path in this post ...)
```

Thus, when I try to sync project with gradle files, a new message from editor arrives:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'NutriMondoProject'
Project is using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in.
The minimum supported version is 0.7.0.
Please update the version of the dependency 'com.android.tools.build:gradle'
    in your build.gradle files.
Search in build.gradle files
```

I feel like a fish out of water.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have updated to Android Studio 0.4.0

it requires gradle plugin 0.7.+ and gradle-wrapper 1.9.

Change your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
```

Then change your gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

Then sync your project with gradle files.
Launch gradlew clean to clean your build.

Comment: "Then change your gradle-wrapper.properties" - which file is this in and where do I find the file?

Comment: I have a <project-root>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file, but not sure if it is this one I need to modify. Currently in the same situation as you, will update this as soon as I get something!

Comment: The gradle-wrapper.properties  is located in <project-root>/gradle/wrapper/

Comment: I'd just like to comment as well, had this issue when updating to 04+ and did the above steps.. Except for the downloading new gradle was in excess of 30 minutes.. After searching n googling.. It was the gradle.org server running slow on download 10kbs. Manual download was an option.. In the Users\.gradle folders there are also a zip.part file that shows the progress of the download... this might be handy for some people. "gradlew clean" here is the key also

Answer (score 3):

It's because you updated your Android Studio to version 0.4.0.

**Follow those steps to make it work :**

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio040released