# Problems with Android Studio - "Please specify Android SDK"

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated to the newest version of Android Studio, and started a fresh, empty project. After finishing the wizard, I opened the main `Activity.java` file, and there was a message that said:

> `Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly`

I found that I should try the button *Sync Project with Gradle Files*. This produces another error:

> Failed to refresh Gradle project. Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager

I tried to open the Android SDK manager and got *another* error:

> `Please specify Android SDK`

So I went into my Project Structure, which has two sections, 'app' and 'Android SDK'. Android SDK points correctly to the Android SDK directory, and app is blank.

[image]

[image]

What should I do?

I tried downloading the [latest SDK bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) and pointing to that in the Project Structure instead, but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. 




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679361/updating-android-studio-to-version-0-4-0-nothing-works-which-fixes

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. After updateing to AS 0.4.2 from 0.3.7 I received the error: "Gradle Project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly..."

What I did was to delete the content of .gradle folder and modify the gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip

Now it works, I don't know if it's the solution for you, but be sure to backup files before deleting them :)

Comment: It was a brand new project so I deleted it and started again and it worked for some reason.

Comment: I opened AS again and I had the same error. After rebooting it disappeared, I thing it's a bug.

Answer (score -1):

i know this answer may have been posted before but next time you get such an error after updating sdk,click on file->Invalidate caches/restart. This solution works perfectly for me.